# array giving weird result made from HTML

Tags: php, html, arrays

**html :**

```
<input type="text" name="ps[part1['test']]" value="testing multiple array">
```

**Current result :**

```
[ps] => Array
    (
        [part1['test'] => testing multiple array 
    )
```

**Expecting result :**

```
[ps] => Array
    (
        [part1] => Array
            (
                [test] => 12:00
            )

    )
```

Last quote is being break somewhere

is there anything missing ?

Comment: Needs more PHP code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `ps['part1']['test']` as the name of the input:

```
<input type="text" name="ps['part1']['test']" value="testing multiple array">
```

This way - when you `POST` the data to PHP it will get into the `$_POST['ps']`, create an array with the key `part1`, and then create another key with the name `test` inside  `$_POST['ps']['part1']`.